# como puedo usar este caracter (*) repetidas veces en python3?

Tags: python, print

ejemplo:

```
a=**********
print'a'
```

**Me muestra el siguiente error**

```
OUTPUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1
    a=**********
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Ya que `a` almacena una cadena, ésta ha de ir entre comillas: `a="*********"`. Puedes usar el operador "producto" para repetir un carácter un número dado de veces. Por ejemplo, para 20 asteriscos: `a="*" * 20`. Aparte de eso no quieres `print 'a'`, que imprimiría una a, sino `print a`, que imprimirá lo que hay en la variable `a`.

Answer (score 1):

La idea es correcta sin embargo en **Python 3** debes usar

1. en la función `print` parántesis `()` para lograr imprimir el valor deseado

Además de eso

2. el otro error es que declaras una variable `a` pero cuando la usas en el `print` la metes entre comillas y eso es incorrecto por que al ponerla así `'a'` le estas diciendo que imprima una cadena de texto que vale **a**

Además de eso

3. los asteriscos deberás meterlos entre comillas, pues al ser un carácter se estaría interpretando de forma errónea por que por ejemplo `*` es el símbolo para representar el operador de multiplicación

Así, será funcional

```
a= "**********"
print(a)
```

*Resultado final*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

intenta así, los caracteres `*` son reservados por eso los tienes que usar como texto.

```
a='**********'
print(a)
```